# Instance of _Future<int> is all I get when I try to get the total 'document' of my 'collection' in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

Following is my code. I'm trying to get all the 'Babies' which are in documents:

```
class _HomePageeState extends State<HomePagee> {
  String t_babies = getCount().toString();
}

Future getCount() async {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Babies').snapshots().length;
}
```

Instead I get this error: `instance of \_future\<int\>`

[image]

Here is my Database. I expect to get 2 counts:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use await when getting Future values and also you should pass Future and the type `Future<int>`:

```
Future<int> getCount() async {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Babies').snapshots().length;
}
```

and also get the method using await but inside and async function:

```
void example() async {  // <---- here the async you need to add to use await
      int babiesLength = await getCount();  // here use await
    }
```

Comment: Can you put an example on how should I add await when getting the method? I tried your suggestion but I get this error 
"The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'."

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setState` to update the string , because the fetch takes time as it involves network.

```
String t_babies = '';

  Future<void> _getCount() async {
    setState((){
        t_babies = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Babies').snapshots().length.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCount();
  }
```